# Don't replace null with zero in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I wrote a mongo shell script to insert in a new collection the result of an aggregation; my problem is that the null values from the source collection are replaced by zero; the aggregation part is:

```
db.getCollection("unhcr_pop_concern_flat").aggregate(
    [ 
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "country" : "$country", 
                    "time" : "$time",
                    "origin": "$origin"
                },
      "value_fields": {
        "$addToSet": {
          k: "$type",
          v: {$ifNull: ["$value", null]}
        }
      }
            }
        },
        { $addFields: { value_fields: { $arrayToObject: "$value_fields" } } }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : true
    }
```

Where is the problem? I have also used the $ifnull operator.

Comment: Can you share some data?

Answer (score 0):

The query is working correctly; there was a problem in the source collections where data were changed by others!